# How to convert rows of data into a single row through informatica/SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, informatica

How to convert diagonal rows into single row in SQL Server 2014 for a particular ID field. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Please review.

My source is SQL Server 2014

Note:

1. I don't have write access to DB so will not be able to create functions etc.
2. I have option to get the desired o/p either by taking the source[given below] in Informatica  from SQL Server - which is in turn result of a query and achieve the required o/p by applying some transformation or write logic in SQL server -2014. So in short either i can perform logic using Informatica or through SQL Server in the initial level itself to get the desired o/p.
3. I have several other joins and columns being pulled from different tables along with the below fields

Please review

Regarding Input:

The ID field will be constant, but POS field will be different for a particular ID

There can be 1 to 10 such occurrences of POS field [POS field can have values from 1 -10].DESC1 value from POS =1 will go to DESC1, value of POS 2 will go to desc2 and so on.

Right now I have given only 8 occurrences,but actually there are 10

INPUT:

```
ID|POS|DESC1|desc2|desc3|desc4|desc5|desc6|desc7|desc8|
1|1|ItemA|null|null|null|null|null|null|null                        
1|2|null|ItemB|null|null|null|null|null|null                        
1|3|null|null|Item C|null|null|null|null|null           
1|4|null|null|null|ItemD|null|null|null|null                
1|5|null|null|null|null|ItemE|null|null|null                    
1|6|null|null|null|null|null|value-random|null|null 
1|7|null|null|null|null|null|null|Check!A|null
1|8|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|123456
```

OUTPUT:

```
ID|DESC1|desc2|desc3|desc4|desc5|Desc6|desc7|Desc8
1|ItemA|ItemB|Item C|ItemD|ItemE|value-random|Check!A|123456
```

Comment: Is it possible that some rows will have more than just a single column that is not null?

Comment: Hi, no..only one occurrence each in every row. and rest all will be null

Answer (score 2):

This is simplified because I don't know what your current query looks like but you could use `MAX()` and `GROUP BY` id.

**[DEMO](https://rextester.com/QWWF25296)**

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  MAX(desc1) AS [desc1],
  MAX(desc2) AS [desc2],
  MAX(desc3) AS [desc3],
  MAX(desc4) AS [desc4],
  MAX(desc5) AS [desc5],
  MAX(desc6) AS [desc6],
  MAX(desc7) AS [desc7],
  MAX(desc8) AS [desc8]
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY ID
```